# Counterexample of triangle inequality property for a Real Euclidean Space

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, inner-products

According to Apostol's Calculus Vol. II, Equality holds for the triangle inequality in the following scenarios:

Let $\mathbb{x}$ and $\mathbb{y}$ be two vectors. Then equality holds if

- $\mathbb{x} = c\mathbb{y}$ for $c \geq 0$.

However, it does not state that this is a necessary condition, and neither does [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_Inequality/Vectors_in_Euclidean_Space). My question is: is there a case where equality holds in the triangle inequality where this condition is not met? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115443/inner-product-spaces-triangle-inequality?rq=1) helps :)

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks. Using the linear dependence equality condition of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality seems so obvious now.